# How to store speech recognition output in a text file

Tags: python, speech

I'm working on a patch in `TouchDesigner` and I want it to use `SpeechRecognition` and build an installation from recorded words/phrases in a table. To do this, I want to be able to save what it prints to a text file, alas I'm a poor programmer, and so far can't get the script to fully work.

To clarify, the speech recognition part is working, and this is a slimmed down original script, leaving only the Google API. What I need is only to write the results ( as they are sent to the console ) to a text file for later use.

This is the part that sends out the recognized words/phrases.

```
 print(u"{}".format(value).encode("utf-8"))
 else: 
 print("{}".format(value))
```

I need the words appended every time ( while the script runs continuously ).

Many thanks for any help.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()


try:


    with m as source: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

       while True:

    with m as source: audio = r.listen(source)
    print("")

    try:

        value = r.recognize_google(audio)

        if str is bytes: 
            print(u"{}".format(value).encode("utf-8"))

         else: 
            print("{}".format(value))

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("{0}".format(e))
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about `speech_recognition`, but if you want help with this you need to fix the formatting of your code. Correct indentation is _vital_ in Python. And you should probably clean up some of those blank lines too.

Comment: To clarify, the speech recognition part is working. Most of the bad indentation is caused by trouble putting the code in here. I only need to print the results to text file - the parts which print this information to the console are highlighted in the code box above. Anyhow, I will work to fix and clean it up.

Answer (score 3):

to output it to a file you'd do something like

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()


try:
    with m as source: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

        while True:

    with m as source: audio = r.listen(source)
    print("")

    try:

        value = r.recognize_google(audio)

        if str is bytes: 
            result = u"{}".format(value).encode("utf-8")

        else: 
            result = "{}".format(value)

        with open("outputs.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(result)
        print(result)

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("{0}".format(e))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

What my addition `with open ...` does is append to a file. `with x as y:` is pythons way of creating an `x` as a `y` that you're only gonna use in that bit of script. `open("all_outputs.txt","a")` opens the file all_outputs.txt as the output file (it creates it if it doesn't exist) and "a" sets it as an append, so it just adds whatever you write at the end. `f.write(result)` writes your result to that output file.

Comment: Many thanks for you reply! When I try to add that piece for script ( with open... ) It always crashes immediately. The cmd window opens and then closes, and there is no time to even make any input. I did try other examples from the web, but it always ends up the same. The write script works standalone of course.

Comment: Aha, it says 'incosistent formatting' in the milisecond that the window flashes on. Somehow the formatting of the piece of code always messes it up, but whatever I try to fix it, doesnt help.

Comment: I downloaded an IDE and played around for a bit, and miraculously fixed it.

Comment: @xmrazak ah yeah it's probably because the indentations might have been a bit messed up in the code I posted. Python likes to complain if you mix tabs and spaces in code. Fixed it in my answer. Glad to have helped! Please accept my answer as the answer.